# Validate arrray name[] input with values Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Good afternoon/evening/night

I am trying to validate from my Laravel controller an empty name array.

In this case it is the following code in blade.php:

```
<input type="text" name='ambito[]' placeholder='Ambit name' class="form-control @error('ambito[]') is-invalid @enderror"/>
```

And my controler has the next code:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'ambito' => 'Required|array|min:2',
    'ambito.*' => 'Required|min:3'

]);
```

I tried this too:

```
$data = $request->validate([
     "ambito"  => 'required|array|min:1',
     'ambito.*' => 'required|string'
]);
```

**But I don't get the error from the form.** I have searched a lot and the truth is that the options I have seen have not worked for me.

Output to dd($request['ambito'])

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "test1"
  1 => "test2"
  2 => "testasfd"
]
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Looks like all array entrys have length > 3. That's why they pass the validation. Or am I missing something?

Comment: what's not working here?? the request will pass the validation as per the code

Comment: I have 3 inputs with the name='ambito[]' I did it to test but I still don't get the error message from Laravel on the form.

Comment: Do you want less than 3 values? 
In this case you have to use `max:2` instead of `min:2`.

Comment: I've fixed it, below I've put what my bug was and its solution, thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

**I've fixed it guys!** The problem was not the Laravel validate but the HOW to return the message in the blade.php.

```
<input type="text" name='ambito[]' placeholder='Nom àmbit' class="form-control @error('ambito[]') is-invalid @enderror"/>
@error('ambito[]')
<span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
    <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
</span>
@enderror
```

Code fixed:

```
<input type="text" name='ambito[]' placeholder='Nom àmbit' class="form-control @error('ambito') is-invalid @enderror"/>
@error('ambito')
<span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
    <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
</span>
@enderror
```

The problem is @error('ambito[]<--')  **it doesnt work with []**

Thanks to all guys!!!